# Play Framework 2 + Couchbase, should I translate json to scala models?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, models, couchbase

I'm working with Play 2 + Scala + Couchbase, with jQuery, HTML5, CSS in the view.

I've got Couchbase json documents / view results returning from ajax requests etc. Controller paths to access such data are defined in Play's routes file, and the json response is returned / rendered. (I've been playing around with various methods)

Currently I am just testing things out and am using javascript (jQuery) to pull out the json document elements of interest and render a html based representation of each to the page. I'm not writing any changes back yet, but will be doing so when I finalize my approach.

My question is, given the setup do you think I should be translating the json data into equivalent Scala model objects in the controller?

Pouchdb looks really interesting, but I don't know if it works well with couchbase views. This is something that I may look to integrate in future.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Liftweb's json parser makes quick work of my json docs so I can easily extract them into Scala case classes. Still working on the ideal approach for my app, but this works well and the data is much more manageable when it's converted...